# Labelling the residuals on diagnostic plots

Tags: r, colors, data-visualization, diagnostics

I have made a linear regression model in R with 3 continuous independent variables and one continuous dependent variable.  I have generated the diagnostic plots.

I would now like to label/colour the data points for each residual on my diagnostic plots according to the binary categorical independent variable that was not included in the model;

i.e. when this variable = A, I want a blue dot on my diagnostic plot, 
and when this variable = B, I want a red dot, so there will be red and blue dots on my diagnostic plots.

I would love some advice on how to  do this.

Answer (score 0):

[You don't specify what diagnostic plots you're trying to do this to. You also haven't given a minimal reproducible example, which makes it difficult to alter what you were doing to do what you want.]

I'll give an example of the kind of command that does what you need and you may be able to adapt it to whatever displays you need.

```
 library(MASS)
 catsmdl <- lm(Hwt~Bwt,cats)
 plot(residuals(catsmdl)~fitted(catsmdl), col=cats$Sex)
 abline(h=0, col=8, lty=3)
```

which gives:

[image]

This even works with `plot.lm`, because it has a `...` argument to pass information along to the lower level plotting functions. So for example:

```
opar <- par()
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(catsmdl,col=c("blue","darkorange")[as.numeric(cats$Sex)])
par(opar)
```

[image]

If you replace `c("blue","darkorange")` with whatever colours you like, it should work. (There are a variety of ways to specify colours in R.)